# How to get User Data from account.html page? - BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm planning to render a page from my private app by passing user id using an iframe. To do that, I need to fetch logged in user's id. How can I get that?

I tried the following options, other than for GLOBAL_StoreName, nothing comes up.

```
<h3>%%GLOBAL_AccountPhone%%</h3>
<h3>%%GLOBAL_AccountFirstName%%</h3>
<h2>%%GLOBAL_StoreName%%</h2>
<h2>%%GLOBAL_CustomerId%%</h2>
<h2>%%GLOBAL_CustomerEmail%%</h2>
<h2>%%GLOBAL_CustomerPhone%%</h2>
```

I'm planning to pass the info through an iframe in the src url.

```
<iframe src="https://custom-app.herokuapp.com/account?id=<ID>" width="100%" height="1000px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Update**

I was able to get current customer first name and last name, but not the Id.
`%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerFirstName%%`
`%% GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerLastName%%`

Comment: Have you tried {{customer.id}}?

Comment: @KarenWhite It just prints as {{customer.id}} in the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{customer.id}} should return the ID of the logged in customer on a Stencil theme, but for Blueprint (legacy) themes, there is not a storewide global variable that will return the customer ID. %%GLOBAL_CustomerId%% is only invoked in the template file for the form to reset the customer's password.

As an alternative, your app can use the Current Customer API to return the current customer's ID, email, and customer group: 
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#current-customer-api

Comment: In case if I'm using Stencil theme and I have a custom field called AccountId, how do I access it in the UI?

Comment: Custom form fields aren't a part of the Stencil {{customer}} object. I think the best way to get that information would be to take the customer ID returned by the Current Customer API and use it to make a request to the v2 customer resource to get the full customer details.